# Using Autofac with ASP.NET and the MVP pattern

Tags: asp.net, mvp, autofac

I'm trying to integrate Autofac into an exsisting ASP.NET web application.

The pages follow the MVP pattern.  Each page implements a View and delegate functionality to a Presenter.  The View is injected into the Presenter thru the constructor.

I was able to register the Presenter and View and the page loads fine but when a postback happens the user controls on the view are null.  It seems that Autofac creates a new instance of the Page to give to the presenter instead of giving it the instance real Page instance.  Is there a way to have Page instances registered with Autofac?

Has anyone use Autofac with ASP.NET and MVP?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is a better way. First, enable [the Web integration module](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/AspNetIntegration). This will enable automatic property injection into the **Page** instance.

Since your presenter needs the view in its constructor, your page should take a dependency on a presenter **factory** instead of the presenter itself.

So, first you need the presenter factory, which is a delegate with the necessary parameters:

```
public delegate IOCTestPresenter IOCTestPresenterFactory(IIOCTestView view);
```

This delegate must match the parameters (type and name) of the presenter constructor:

```
public class IOCTestPresenter
{
     public IOCTestPresenter(IIOCTestView view)
     {
     }
}
```

In your view, add a property receiving the factory delegate, and use the delegate to create the presenter:

```
public partial class IOCTest
{
     public IOCTestPresenterFactory PresenterFactory {get;set;}

     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)    
     {
           var presenter = PresenterFactory(this);
     }
}
```

In your container setup you will have to make the following registrations:

```
builder.Register<IOCTestPresenter>().FactoryScoped();
builder.RegisterGeneratedFactory<IOCTestPresenterFactory>();
```

Comment: I am facing same issue still the solution is the same for this or is there a fix with the latest Autofact 
i am using Autofact  and  Autofac.Integration.Web V 5.0.0

Comment: @Satti yes, you can still use the Autofac integration libraries for ASP.NET (see https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnet.html)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution.  Basically, you would register the page instance during the Page_PreInit event and then call the container to inject the dependencies.  Ex.

```
public partial class IOCTest : System.Web.UI.Page, IIOCTestView
{

    protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var containerProviderAccessor = (IContainerProviderAccessor)HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance;
        var containerProvider = containerProviderAccessor.ContainerProvider;

        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.Register(this).ExternallyOwned().As<IIOCTestView>();

        builder.Build(containerProvider.RequestContainer);

        containerProvider.RequestContainer.InjectProperties(this);
    }

    public IOCTestPresenter Presenter { get; set; }
```

I'm not sure if there is a better way, but this seems to work.