# MVP Autofac and Controllers

Tags: c#, mvp, autofac

I have a page like so -

```
public partial class ProductDetailMixed : SessionPage, IProductDetailMixedView
{
        public IProductService ProductService { get; set; }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Controller = new ProductDetailMixedController(this, ProductService);

            OnLoadPage();
        }

        public event LoadPageEvent OnLoadPage;

        public IProductDetailMixedController Controller { get; set; }
}
```

I have property injection so the instance of IProductService will be injected into the page, however what I would really like is to just create the controller like so -

```
Controller = new ProductDetailMixedController(this);
```

And then the Constructor of ProductDetailMixedController will just inject all the remaining parameters.. but how do I do this??

Answer (score 0):

[I believe this is what you're trying to accomplish](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1836456/1742028)?  In the referenced example, your presenter / controller factory would also need a parameter for your service interface.  Once you have something like that in place, you could remove the property injection for your service from your view (unless you utilize it within your view, of course).

Comment: I wire my View up exactly as specified and receive this error - None of the constructors found with 'Public binding flags' on type 'Cell.Common.Controllers.LandingController' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'Cell.Common.Views.Landing.ILandingView view' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Cell.Common.Views.Landing.ILandingView, Cell.Services.Catalog.IContentService, ....

Comment: It seems as though Autofac doesn't know what to do with the view how do I get around this??

Comment: I apologize... I'm not familiar with Autofac as the IoC container.  Having said that, here is another example that might shed some light on the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926437/dependency-injection-for-presenter.

Comment: This line: builder.Register<FooPresenter>().As<IFooPresenter>().FactoryScoped();  can't be registered because it depends on a view which has not been registered....